# Get and replace words in string that contains ? in between of word in string php regex

Tags: php, regex

how does i use php regex to achieve the following :

i have a string that contains :

$a = "Does Foo loves Bar ? i don?t think so, Foo doesn?t.  Okay?";

and i want to get output of :

Does Foo loves Bar ? i don't think so, Foo doesn't.  Okay?

with all the ? *in between of text* replaced with single quote (') .

i have tried the following code but the *Okay?* is also being replaced with *Okay'* :

```
<?php

$str = "This is Agbeniga , he is a very good boy. He?s loved , but is he really is ? No , i don?t think so. but it?s working very good anyway , ya?ll all darling. Okay?";

$str = str_replace("?","0",$str);
//replace all question marks with zero

$divide=explode(" ",$str);
$str="";
foreach($divide as $div)
{
    if(substr($div,0,1)===0)
    {
        $div=preg_replace("/0/", "?",$div);
    }
    $str .= ' ';
    $str.=$div;
}
//split by spaces and replace words that have zero at the end with question mark

$str= preg_replace('/\b(?<!-)\d+(?!-)\b/',"?",$str);
//replace all stand alone zeros with question mark

$str = str_replace("0","'",$str);
//then replace the remaining zeros with single quote

echo  $str;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex can check that on both sides of question mark boundaries of words are placed (`\b')

```
$str = "This is Agbeniga , he is a very good boy. He?s loved , but is he really is ? No , i don?t think so. but it?s working very good anyway , ya?ll all darling. Okay?";
$str= preg_replace('/\b\?\b/',"'",$str);
echo  $str;
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/933759)